# How to catch exception for which the name is not defined in context?

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

I am seeing the [python-requests library](http://www.python-requests.org/) crash with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 529, in _read_chunked
    chunk_left = int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 507, in getUrlContents
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=authCredentials, timeout=http_timeout_seconds)
  File "/home/dotancohen/code/lib/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dotancohen/code/lib/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dotancohen/code/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 338, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/dotancohen/code/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 441, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dotancohen/code/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 340, in send
    r.content
  File "/home/dotancohen/code/lib/requests/models.py", line 601, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "/home/dotancohen/code/lib/requests/models.py", line 542, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/home/dotancohen/code/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 222, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/home/dotancohen/code/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 173, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 489, in read
    return self._read_chunked(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 534, in _read_chunked
    raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(value))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/threading.py", line 740, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "./app.py", line 298, in run
    self.target(*self.args)
  File "./app.py", line 400, in provider_query
    url_contents = getUrlContents(str(providerUrl), '', authCredentials)
  File "./app.py", line 523, in getUrlContents
    except http.client.IncompleteRead as error:
NameError: global name 'http' is not defined
```

As can be seen, I've tried to catch the `http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)` error that `requests` is throwing with the line `except http.client.IncompleteRead as error:`. However, that is throwing a `NameError` due to `http` not being defined. **So how can I catch that exception?**

This is the code throwing the exception:

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

authCredentials = OAuth1('x', 'x', 'x', 'x')
response = requests.get(url, auth=authCredentials, timeout=20)
```

Note that I am not including the `http` library, though `requests` is including it. The error is very intermittent (happens perhaps once every few hours, even if I run the `requests.get()` command every ten seconds) so I'm not sure if added the `http` library to the imports has helped or not.

In any case, in the general sense, **if included library A in turn includes library B, is it impossible to catch exceptions from B without including B myself?**

Comment: can you post your code that is causing this?

Comment: did you forget to `import http`?

Comment: `requests` could raise the `http` error because it imports it https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/compat.py. However for you to use the exception, you must import it yourself, as mentioned by @Brad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question

> In any case, in the general sense, if included library A in turn includes library B, is it impossible to catch exceptions from B without including B myself?

Yes. For example:

`a.py`:

```
import b

# do some stuff with b
```

`c.py`:

```
import a

# but you want to use b
a.b  # gives you full access to module b which was imported by a
```

Although this does the job, it doesn't look so pretty, especially with long package/module/class/function names in real world.

So in your case to handle `http` exception, either try to figure out which package/module within `requests` imports `http` and so that you'd do `raise requests.XX.http.WhateverError` or rather just import it as `http` is a standard library.

Comment: Interestingly, `requests` does not seem to import `http`: [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/5Cy6qM0X).

Comment: It does, through a very unusual loop that involves urllib3. Requests uses urllib3 as a wrapper around the http package.

Comment: Also a sign of it being imported in requests.compat module https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/compat.py#L104

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to analyze the problem if you don't give source and just the stout,
but check this link out : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions

Basically,
try and catch the exception whereever the error is rising in your code.
Exceptions:

```
In the event of a network problem (e.g. DNS failure, refused connection, etc), 
Requests will raise a **ConnectionError** exception.

In the event of the rare invalid HTTP response, 
Requests will raise an **HTTPError** exception.

If a request times out, a **Timeout** exception is raised.

If a request exceeds the configured number of maximum redirections,
 a **TooManyRedirects** exception is raised.

All exceptions that Requests explicitly raises inherit 
from **requests.exceptions.RequestException.**
```

Hope that helped.